# Embedding of real trees into $\ell_1(\Gamma)$

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, banach-spaces, trees

It seems plausible that any real tree or ${\mathbb{R}}$-tree in the sense of the definition in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_tree admits an isometric embedding into the Banach space $\ell_1(\Gamma)$ for a set $\Gamma$ of sufficiently large cardinality (the space $\ell_1(\Gamma)$ is defined as the space of real-valued functions on $\Gamma$ with countable support and norm $||f||=\sum_{\gamma\in\hbox{supp} f}|f(\gamma)|$). My question is:

Is this known? If "Yes", I would appreciate references.

P.S. I like the proof of this fact suggested by Yves de Cornulier (see below). I also agree with Bill Johnson that the fact looks like "well known" and most probably has been published somewhere. If someone knows a reference, I would be very thankful for it (I cannot accept the second answer, but I would be happy to upvote it.)

Comment: What do you mean by an isometric embedding?

Comment: Isometric embedding means map preserving the distance.

Comment: That's an ambiguous term as it could mean either the induced or the ambient distance.

Comment: @katz Well in this context (embeddings of metric spaces into Banach spaces) it's very common to use "isometric" in the global (distance) sense rather than in a local or infinitesimal sense, and I never saw any other use of it such as the one used in Riemannian geometry. By the way "induced distance" itself is ambiguous. What you call "induced distance" is rather an "induced length distance".

Comment: I guess you haven't you read my paper with Lindenstrauss, Preiss, and Schechtman on $\ell_1$-trees.  Embed any interval or half line of the tree into a one dimensional space. Take any branch point and add a new  $\ell_1$ dimension and move an interval or ray branching off in this new direction.  Continue transfinitely.

Comment: @BillJohnson There are 3 papers with the same 4-tuple of authors; I guess you refer to this one http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123602939248 (JLPS, Lipschitz Quotients from Metric Trees and from Banach Spaces Containing l1, J. Funct. Anal. 194 (2002), no. 2, 332–346). Where exactly do you prove this? I indeed see the ingredients of the proof at some places but can't single out the precise statement.

Comment: @YCor Yes, that is the paper.  I don't have the paper with me here.  It is where we describe the constructive procedure for building a general $\ell_1$-tree.   We do not state it as result that real trees embed isometrically into $\ell_1$ spaces, which we assumed was well known.

Comment: @Bill I have not noticed this result stated explicitly in your paper. I also sketched a proof of the fact obtained by transfinite enumeration of all geodesics (which is more complicated than the proof by Yves below). The point is that I needed the fact that all trees are embeddable into RNP spaces to abandon some direction of thought, and I wanted to be sure that I did not do so prematurely. I asked the question to become sure in this.

Comment: @Bill P.S. I agree with Bill that it is highly probable that this fact
is "well known" in the sense that it was published in a relatively
old source. I will be very thankful for a reference. I still find
it amazing that something so highly branching can admit an
isometric embedding into a Banach space with the Radon-Nikodym
property and therefore (by Gelfand's theorem) an embedding of each
line in the tree is differentiable almost everywhere.

Comment: @Mikhail Ostrovskii:  Do you know of any one dimensional metric space that does not embed into an RNP Banach space?

Comment: @katz By an isometric embedding in my question I mean a map $F:T\to \ell_1(\Gamma)$ such that for any two elements $u,v\in T$ we have $d_{\ell_1(\Gamma)}(F(u),F(v))=d_T(u,v)$.

Comment: @Bill Johnson: I never thought about this. It seems that the answer depends on the notion of dimension. For example the Laakso space, that is the union of all Laakso graphs does not embed into RNP-spaces, and Cheeger and Kleiner (GAFA 2013) consider it as having Lipschitz dimension 1. If we look at Hausdorff dimension, the standard
definition of it (e.g. as in Mattila, Geometry of sets and measures, Chapter 4) does not seem to be applicable to trees which cannot be covered by countably many balls with uniformly bounded
radii

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's true: there's an isometric embedding of every real tree $T$ on some $\ell^1$-space, i.e., a set $A$ and a map $f:T\to \ell^1(A)$ that is an isometric embedding, that is, satisfies $\|f(x)-f(x')\|=d(x,x')$ for all $x\in T$.

I don't know a reference; here's a proof. Let $(x_t)_{t<\alpha}$ be an enumeration of points on the real tree $T$ by an ordinal $\alpha$, assume that the convex hull of them is $T$.

Let $T_\beta$ be the closed convex hull of $\{x_t:t<\beta\}$ (so $T_\alpha=T$). Let us construct by induction an isometric embedding $f_\beta:T_\beta\to\ell^1(\beta)\subset\ell^1(\alpha)$, so that whenever $\beta\le\gamma$ then $f_\gamma$ extends $f_\beta$.

For $\beta=1$, $T_\beta=\{x_0\}$, and we just prescribe $f_\beta(x_0)=0$. For $\beta=\gamma+1>1$ a successor ordinal, $T_\beta$ is the convex hull of $T_\gamma\cup\{x_\gamma\}$. Let $y_\gamma$ be the projection of $x_\gamma$ on $T_\gamma$. So $$T_\beta=T_\gamma\cup [y_\gamma,x_\gamma].$$ We define $f_\beta$ so as to extend $f_\gamma$ on $T_\gamma$, and prescribe $f_\beta(y)=f_\gamma(y_\gamma)+d(y,y_\gamma)e_\beta$ for every $y\in [y_\gamma,x_\gamma]$, where $(e_t)$ is the canonical basis of $\ell^1(\alpha)$ and $d$ is the distance in the tree. This is well-defined (note that $f_\gamma(y_\gamma)$ is defined twice) and defines an isometric embedding. Finally, for $\beta$ a limit ordinal, then $T_\beta$ is the closure of $T'_\beta=\bigcup_{\gamma<\beta}T_\gamma$, we just define $f_\beta$ on $T'_\beta$ by saying its graph is the union of graphs of all $f_\gamma$ for $\gamma<\beta$; this is an isometric embedding into a complete metric space, so extends uniquely to an isometric embedding of the closure $T_\beta$ into $\ell^1(\beta)$.

So $f_\alpha$ is the required isometric embedding.

Comment: @Yves. Thank you. I also produced something like this, but less organized than your argument and I was thinking that probably better-organized arguments are known and published.